# Pagination in AngularJS / JavaScript from Nodejs application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I am trying to implement the simplest pagination in my website. I do not know where to start. I am a beginner at Web Development.

Here is my code for my index.html:

```
<div ng-controller="searchCtrl">
<h2 id="zoekTable">Zoeken</h2>
<form>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-edit" ng-click="searchSystem()">Zoek</button> <button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="displayAllUsers()">Toon alle gebruikers</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<h2>Gebruikers</h2>
<table class="table" id="tableResults">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Gebruikersnaam</td>
            <td>Volledige naam</td>
            <td>Woonplaats</td>
            <td>Bezit rijbewijs</td>
            <td>Bekijk CV</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-if="results.length === 0">
        <td>Geen.</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="results.length !== 0" ng-repeat="result in results">
        <td>{{result.gebruikersnaam}}</td>
        <td>{{result.naam}}</td>
        <td>{{result.woonplaats}}</td>
        <td>{{result.rijbewijs==1?"Ja":"Nee"}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="viewCV(result.gebruikersnaam)">Bekijk CV</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Here is my code for my AngularJS side:

```
app.controller('searchCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
$scope.displayAllUsers = function () {
    $http.get("/gebruikers")
            .success(function (users) {
                success2("Gebruikers gevonden!", "zoekTable");
                $scope.results = users;
            })
            .error(function (err) {
                alert(err);
                clearResults();
            });
};

    function clearResults() {
        $scope.results = "";
        $scope.results.length = 0;
    }
});
```

And finally my Node.Js code:

```
app.get("/gebruikers", function (req, res) {
var rijen;
l("Bezig met ophalen van gebruikers...");
connection.query("SELECT * FROM gebruikers INNER JOIN personalia ON gebruikers.gebruikersnaam = personalia.gebruikersnaam WHERE done='1';", function (err, rows) {
    if (err) {
        l("ERROR: " + err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    } else {
        if (rows.length >= 1) {
            rijen = rows;
            l("Gebruikers gevonden!");
            res.status(200).send(rows);
        } else {
            l("Geen gebruikers gevonden!");
            res.status(404).send("!Geen gebruikers gevonden!");
        }
    }
});
});
```

I maybe getting 1000 users from my database and I would like to add pagination as simple as possible. Hoe can I do that?

Comment: [Worth a read](http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/108/paginate-almost-anything-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

Your backend needs to be able to handle two params. Limit and Skip. Limit is the number of records you will be fetching, skip is the number of records you will omit.

So you need something like this:

```
$scope.page = function(_page) {
    var query = {
      skip: 50 * (_page - 1),
      limit: 50
    };
}
```

If page is 1 you will omit 0 records. If page is 2, you will omit 50...and so on.

You will need to combine this with the proper query in the backend plus as  @GillesC mentioned, check out that pagination directive for Angular. http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/108/paginate-almost-anything-in-angularjs